# Ripping XAML from a .Net assembly

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to get Xaml details from an assembly?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) supports decompiling BAML to XAML.

Under the resources section, find the `<assemblyName>.g.resources` and there is the BAML, which ILSpy will decompile into XAML.

Comment: Nice tool - I am glad to see a replacement for Reflector! I can see how a baml file would work with ILSpy, but can you take a WPF app executable and view the XAML markup? I have tried, but can only see the C# code that is not part of the code behind.

Comment: The BAML should be located in the assembly resources. I haven't actually used ILSpy yet, but I guess I should.

Comment: I was looking for the resource section but couldn't find it. Turns out the problem was I didn't look hard enough. Under the resources section, find the <assemblyName>.g.resources and there is the BAML, which ILSpy did decompile into XAML for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Telerik JustDecompile also support BAML to XAML.