# How to extract code of XAML files from executable file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, decompiling

we have noticed lately that we don't' have source code of some desktop applications (WPF) created by one of our developer. Applications are already used by production (I know it's shame...)
I have tried to decompile these apps via JetBrains dotPeek, but I cannot extract xaml code.
Is there any way to decompile .NET app including xaml files?

To be more precised, I have checked also ILSPY but it seems that there are no baml files under Resources in ILSPY (please see attached )

[image: picture]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ripping XAML from a .Net assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935215/ripping-xaml-from-a-net-assembly)

Comment: There's a dotpeek plugin iirc.

Answer (score 1):

From [dotpeek features](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/features/).

> dotPeek can also decompile .baml files, enabling you to reconstruct XAML UI definitions.

Go to the resources entry of your assembly and look for entries ending with "g.resources", this should contain .baml files for your various controls and views. Opening the .baml file should show you the decompiled xaml. This is using dotPeek 2021.1.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but if you see picture in my post, you can notice that there is missing "g.resources". I have created empty project called WpfApp5 and for this project there is "g.resources" and mainwindow.baml but for target decompiled app it's missing.

Comment: @marspox are you sure they are there in the first place? The project might be using winforms, or even be a wrapper around native UI-code.